# Какие заголовки нужно отправить браузеру, чтобы он перестал грузить страницу? [решено]

Tags: c++

Есть сервер на c++, он может читать сообщения, приходящие на заданный порт, и отвечать на них, если вбить в браузере ip и порт, то браузер будет тупо грузить страницу до бесконечности, т.к. серв не отдает нужные заголовки. Какие заголовки нужно отдать браузеру и в каком виде?

Спасибо, разобрался, я в конце просто не закрывал сокет=)

```
Вот код рабочего примера

#include < iostream >
#pragma comment( lib, "ws2_32.lib" )
#include < Windows.h >
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int MY_PORT = 1001; // Порт, который слушает сервер

DWORD WINAPI WorkWithClient(LPVOID client_socket);

int user[100];

int main()
{

    char buff[1024];
    printf("TCP SERVER DEMO\n");
    WSAStartup(0x0202, (WSADATA *)&buff[0]);
    SOCKET mysocket;
    mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    // Шаг 3 связывание сокета с локальным адресом
    sockaddr_in local_addr;
    local_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local_addr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
    local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
    bind(mysocket, (sockaddr *)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr));
    listen(mysocket, 20);
    printf("Waiting for connection \n");

    SOCKET client_socket;
    sockaddr_in client_addr;

    int client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);

    while ((client_socket = accept(mysocket, (sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addr_size)))
    {
        cout << inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr) << " nowii konect!\n";
        DWORD thID;
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, WorkWithClient, &client_socket, NULL, &thID);
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI WorkWithClient(LPVOID client_socket)
{
    SOCKET my_sock = ((SOCKET *)client_socket)[0];

    cout << " con " << endl;

    send(my_sock, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-length: 100\nconnection: close \n\ntext", 1000, 0);

    char buff[5000];

        int bytes_recv = recv(my_sock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
        if (bytes_recv>0){
            cout << "pismo" << endl;
        }
        closesocket(my_sock);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Kopkan, а про HTTP протокол Вы что-нибудь читали?

Comment: При отдаче заголовка HTTP/1.0 200 OK ничего не изменяется.

Comment: @Kopkan, хм, у меня вот это

    avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ncat -l localhost 1234
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:1234
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-length: 10
    connection: close
    
    e3uueuue3
    avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ 


отработало.

Возможно, у Вас проблема с Content-length:

Comment: @Kopkan, Вы именно тот текст, что в примере отправляете? Или все-таки `\r\n` съедены копипастом?

Обратите внимание, Content-Length это размер именно текста, который Вы собираетесь отобразить в браузере, и он отделяется от заголовков пустой строкой (`\r\n`), размер которой не учитывается.

--

А вообще-то (IMHO) по минимуму в заголовках достаточно послать:

    http/1.0 200
    connection: close

    текст сообщения

Теперь можно просто закрыть сокет, и увидите свой текст в браузере.

--

Зачем Вам нужны игры с `user[]`, в котором запоминается закрываемый сокет, -- не понимаю.

Comment: @avp: `Connection: close` нужно только для HTTP/1.1 и если Content-Length не установлен. В http/1.0 можно даже без Content-Length. Например, `socat TCP-LISTEN:1234,crlf,reuseaddr SYSTEM:"echo HTTP/1.0 200 OK; echo; date"` команда отображает дату, если браузером зайти на `http://localhost:1234`. Заголовок `Content-Length` не нужен, если сервер закрывает соединение после отсылки тела. В вопросе не хватает Host заголовка, разделитель  должен быть \r\n (хотя \n тоже разрешается)

Comment: @jfs, согласен. Минимально достаточно просто ответить: 

    http/1.0 200\r\n
    \r\n
    text ...

и закрыть сокет. 

Собственно, при существующем "разборе" автором запроса, его чтение можно вообще опустить.